# Error while testing coffee-resque sample code

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

The following error occurs on testing coffee-resque.

```
> coffee test/connection_enqueue_test.coffee 
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

Steps I had followed:

1. installed coffee-reseque using npm
2. copied Makefile and test folder from the source code
3. run `make test`

Please suggest why this error occurs. I have already installed coffee-script.